# Building an array with select and objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to build an array that allows users to select from a set of options.  I have a generic array of objects, and when I add a new item to my model, I am able to select one of those objects.

The problem I'm having (I believe) is that the `ng-options` I'm using to populate the list of items get's cleared once a user makes a selection.  I'm not sure how to keep the full list of objects so that the user can change their mind if they want to.

I put together a quick sample of what I'm trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/b0kwx1nj/

I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ToppingCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.toppings = [{
    name: 'Cheese',
    price: 0.5
  }, {
    name: 'Ham',
    price: 1.5
  }, {
    name: 'Sauce',
    price: 0.25
  }];
  $scope.myToppings = [];

  $scope.addTopping = function() {
    var newTopping = angular.copy($scope.toppings);
    $scope.myToppings.push(newTopping);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ToppingCtrl" class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Topping</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in myToppings track by $index">
            <td>
                <select
                    id="top_{{$index}}"
                    name="top_{{$index}}"
                    title="top_{{$index}}"
                    ng-model="myToppings[$index]"
                    ng-options="topping.name for topping in myToppings[$index]"
                >
                    <option value=''>-- select --</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>{{myToppings[$index].price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="addTopping()">Add topping</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the steps we take in your fiddle to get the error? Click "Add toppings" and then choose from the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's getting cleared is `addTopping()` converts the `myToppings[$index]` to an array containing 3 elements from `toppings` which shows up as the dropdown list.

It gets converted to a single element (not an array anymore) as soon as you make a selection in your dropdown - and that's why the value doesn't stick. You should link the `ng-options` to `toppings` instead of `myToppings[$index]` to correct that. And, you can just change the `addToppings()` to add a new empty object to the `myToppings[]`.

Here's your new code:

HTML:

```
<select
id="top_{{$index}}"
name="top_{{$index}}"
title="top_{{$index}}"
ng-model="myToppings[$index]"
ng-options="topping.name for topping in toppings"
>
    <option value=''>-- select --</option>
</select>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.addTopping = function() {
var newTopping = {};
$scope.myToppings.push(newTopping);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-options` to return the entire `topping` object and use the `as label` clause to show the topping name in the selector:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myToppings track by $index">
    <td>
        <select
            id="top_{{$index}}"
            name="top_{{$index}}"
            title="top_{{$index}}"
            ng-model="item"
            <!-- REPLACE
            ng-options="topping.name for topping in myToppings[$index]"
            -->
            <!-- INSTEAD -->
            ng-options="topping as topping.name for topping in toppings"

            <option value=''>-- select --</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mh0tfL3/)